# Multiple arguments passed to function as union type

Tags: java

I was looking to find a way to pass multiple enumerations to a method. One way to do it is

```
public enum State{
    A,
    B,
    C;
}
public void foo(State...states){
    // handle
}

// And call it like
foo(State.A,State.B);
```

But I am curios if there is a way to use the idiom for multiple catch clauses

```
} catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
```

So that you can call it like

```
foo(State.A | State.B)
```

I apologize for the title, but I do not know how to call this. Please suggest a better title.

**EDIT**

I am not expecting an answer that the first version already does what I am asking and that the second construct is not possible .

I want to know why it is not possible. If the syntactic of Java allows for the use of the | operator in the catch clauses, why it is not possible to use it in development.

Comment: Why do you think that this could be possible, and what advantage would it have over the current way to call the method? (and the answer is no, it is not possible)

Comment: Please state you actual problem.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What you have already, `(State... states)` and comma-separated states, already basically does what you need. You can't use `|` on objects.

Comment: So it would do the exact same thing as currently only with `|` instead of `,`? Apart from people working with keyboards where the `,` key is broken what would be the advantage?

Comment: `"what I am asking and that the second construct is not possible ."` -- simply because it is not syntactically correct Java. Period. End of story.

Comment: Idiom which is used in "multicatch" allows users to express something which called a [Union type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type). The multicatch is the only place in Java where this is currently possible.

Comment: Maybe you want something like `EnumSet.of(State.A, State.B)`

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thank you for the name reference. Basically you are allowed to do this  `<T extends IA & IB> void whatEver(T  e);` (which makes sense), but not this `<T extends IA | IB> void whatEver(T  e);` (which is a bit odd), but somehow would like to see it being matched to a common anchestor by the compiler

Comment: @GyroGearless I did not think of that to be onest, but it looks like a good idea.

Comment: @RaduIonescu Union types in method arguments parameters are not supported because if the types indeed have nothing in common, you might as well just accept `Object`. If you want type safe "union-like" resolution, then this is what method overloading is for. Just define two methods, and join their logic with third method where appropriate.

Comment: @RaduIonescu, as for intersection (`T extends A & B`) types, then this is a valid requirement from a method standpoint, because you say (I want something which conforms both of these two contracts, basically as if you implemented an `interface T extends A, B {}`). There is no similar semantic for unions in Java, you cannot define `interface T extends A or B {}`, that doesn't make much sense except as a return type of something. In latter sense java indeed loses to newer languages like Kotlin.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov could you please post an answer with your comments. It is a valid point. I do agree strongly with the return type that it does not need to be covariant

Comment: Some comments sound as if a feature like this was inconceivable, but C# enums can be used exactly like this and it's a useful feature. Sure, C# enums are way more simple and backed by primitive types, but I don't see why this couldn't be syntactic sugar for an EnumSet. The actual question "why it is not possible" is not good though, that could be asked for like every possible feature that is not part of the language.

Comment: @Kapep, it wouldn't really be a good idea to "sugar" over the `EnumSet`, like this, because in the end it's still a `Set<T>`. You'd then be faced with either `(State.A | State.B).contains(State.C)` and other variations of, or you will have to also "sugar" the `Set.contains` so that something along the lines of `value == (State.A | State.B)` is possible (and then there's even more confusion than there was before. I would say that `EnumSet.of` (and `Set.of` in Java 9) are already good enough.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I agree that `EnumSet` is good enough and in my experience flag-like enums aren't that common in Java anyway. It's still nice to be able to do bitwise operation with enums in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two general type interactions that Java language allows you to do:

[**Intersection type**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_type)

Can be expressed via generic types for method arguments:

```
<T extends A & B> void doSomething(T arg);
```

This is a declared expectation from the method `doSomething` that its argument should be a subtype of both `A` and `B`. This can works when at least one of `A` or `B` is an interface type, and is directly representable via normal Java class, such as these:

```
interface T extends A, B { }

class T extends A implements B {

   <... implemented  methods from B ...>
}
```

[**Union type**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type)

This means that the type in question is either `A` or `B`. Currently this only works in Java in "try-multicatch":

```
try {
  <... a piece of code ...>
}
catch (ExceptionA | ExceptionB e) {<... handle ...>}
```

In this statement, `ExceptionA` does not need to be in any relation with `ExceptionB` (apart from both being subclasses of `Throwable`, but it is not the point here). This statement also doesn't look for "common superclass" in sense that it doesn't replace the statement with common supertype.

If `ExceptionA` and `ExceptionB` are both instances of `Exception0`, and there is a `ExceptionC extends Exception0`, then above block will not catch neither `ExceptionC`, nor `Exception0` being thrown - this is the "true union type".

There are other places where one might consider using union types is return type of a method. This is something that exists, for example, in [Ceylon](https://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/tour/types/) language. It might be coming to Java, it might not. It, however, can be emulated at library level, using [Either](http://static.javadoc.io/io.javaslang/javaslang/2.0.2/javaslang/control/Either.html) types or tricks like [this one, for example](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/02/16/an-ingenious-workaround-to-emulate-sum-types-in-java/).

---

So, with all that out of the way,

**Why isn't it possible to declare and use something like Enum.A | Enum.B**?

It is rather simple: Java already has "| operator" - a [Bitwise OR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

It is not applicable to `Object`s because there cannot be a general way do to a "bitwise OR" with operands of two `Object` instances due to differences in their structure. Since `enum` instances in Java are objects, this rule also apply in general.

In specific sense, you actually can use enumeration instances in bitwise or operation, but they would have to de defined very specifically:

```
// basically, define a bit-mask
public enum State {
  A(0x00000001),

  B(0x00000002),

  C(0x00000004);

  private final int mask;
  public State(int mask) {
    this.mask = mask;
  }

  public int mask() { return mask; }

  public boolean isPartOf(int mask) {
    return (this.mask & mask) != 0;
  }
}
```

And after you defined enumeration in this way, considering you have method with signature like this, which is admittedly a little uglier than the original version from the question:

```
static void doSomething(int mask) { // the method
   if (State.A.isPartOf(mask)) {
     // we got A
   }
   else <... etc. ...>
}

static {
  doSomething(State.A.mask() | State.C.mask());
}
```

A little note here as well: if you look into implementation of [EnumSet](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/02/16/an-ingenious-workaround-to-emulate-sum-types-in-java/) in Java, the above masking is almost exactly what it internally does with your enumeration values, except it does not require you to bit-mask manually and uses `long` (or array of) instead of an `int`.